# Unable to save new data in firebase 16.0.2

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am unable to save data in Firebase Database. I'm trying to save a new object (mNewThread) under the node "threads". I don't get any errors but also no new data is added to my database.

**In gradle (app) I included:**

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
```

**In MainActivity:**

```
mThreadsDbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

mThreadsDbReference = mThreadsDbReference.child("threads");

mThreadsDbReference.push().setValue(mNewThread);
```

Comment: Can i know why are you using push()? You directly call setValue() without push.

Comment: Have you tried to add a complete listener and log the error? If not, give it a try. Don't ignore errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mThreadsDbReference.push().getKey().setValue(mNewThread);`